# Can anyone help me with the explanation of the processing of this snippet of code

Tags: c, structure, unions

Actually i compiled this in a online c compiler, the output of the code was 5... how did the processing take place??

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct ab {char a,b;};
    union abcd
    {
        int c;
        struct ab d;
    }k;
    k.d.a=5;
    k.d.b=0;
    printf("%d",k.c);
}
```

Comment: accessing another member of an union does that, but only because you have a little endian CPU

Comment: I have a multiple choice question with 4 options... How to identify the correct one

Comment: Something to do with electrons. But accessing another member of a union can result in unexpected results. Please give use the 4 choices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have an union between an integer and a structure containing 2 chars.

The code is changing the first char of the structure. Because of the union, it affects the first byte of the other union member, which is the integer.

On a little-endian machine, setting the first byte of an integer to 5 makes this integer 5 and that's what you're seeing here.

On a big-endian machine you end up with a very big value depending of the actual size of an integer.